# How To create Custom Action

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I want to create one custom action such that on that custom action page one button is available,on that button event i want to show hello word on same custom page

Answer (score 4):

Custom Actions generally are used to link to Application Pages which will do the work.

You can include customactions to the Ribbon, to context menus (ECB), or to the Site Settings pages (as well as Central Administration).

The custom action will typically be a custom section with a link to an application page, and within that page you will perform whatever logic you require. You can pass tokens through to the querystring by enclosing them in parenthesis `{ }` such as `<UrlAction Url="/_layouts/MyApplicationPage.aspx?ListItem={ItemId}" />`

[Here's a link to a tutorial](http://codename-srini.blogspot.com/2010/04/using-custom-actions-in-sharepoint-2010.html) on how to create a custom action to appear in the Site Settings page. Google around for simliar tutorials on how to get a custom action to appear in other areas, such as the Ribbon or the ECB.